# DEV C++ compiless but Visual studio doesn't

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dev-c++

What's wrong in this code? Why 1 compilator says its ok and run it but other , from Microsoft, shout about tons of errors. I can't even find thing is wrong coz bilion of linies of error.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
private:
    static const int LIMIT = 256;
    string lname;
    char fname[LIMIT];
public:
    Person() { lname = "";fname[0] = '\0'; }
    Person(const string & ln , const char* fn = "HejTy") { lname=ln; strncpy(fname,fn,LIMIT);}
    void Show() const {  cout << "nieformalnie: " << fname << " " << lname << endl; }
    void FormalShow() const {  cout << "formalnie: " << lname << " " << fname << endl; }
};
int main(){
    Person one;
    Person two("StaszeK");
    Person three("JACEK", "Placek");
    one.Show();
    cout << endl;
    one.FormalShow();
    two.Show();
    cout << endl;
    two.FormalShow();
    cout << endl;
    three.Show();
    cout << endl;
    three.FormalShow();
        cout << endl; 
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: " I can't even find thing is wrong coz bilion of linies of error." ignore the 999999999 last lines of error messages. The first one ist always the important one. Because that's what the compiler first encountered. The following might be nonsense depending on that error.

Comment: Dev C++ uses old version of MinGW compiler which is not compatible with the newest C++ standard, I recommend you to change your IDE to any newer one (e.g Code::Blocks uses newer MinGW).

Comment: Mine compiles if I `#include <string>` instead of `#include <cstring>`. I'm not sure what errors you're getting so I can't help our more but you can start with that.

Comment: thx all for help. Mahesh comment says everything about issue.

Comment: @micnyk: that's not true, at least not for the following version, which fixes an immense list of bugs, ships with GCC 4.7.1 x64 or 4.7.1, and is fully portable: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the header `<string>`. Include it.

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: I thought <cstring> i same like <string> but with more functions. how is it possible that dev c++ didn't shout for it? Anyway thx bro works now.

Comment: @FilipBartuzi Devc++ does all kind of weird stuff, it just shouldn't be used at all

Comment: @FilipBartuzi: `<cstring>` is the C++ equivalent of the C-style string functions, such as `strcat`, `strdup`, and `strcpy`.